# Flink Job Logs Not Showing up on Flink UI

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have the following session cluster logging configuration setup.

```
      rootLogger.level = INFO
      rootLogger.appenderRef.console.ref = ConsoleAppender
      rootLogger.appenderRef.rolling.ref = RollingFileAppender

      # Uncomment this if you want to _only_ change Flink's logging
      logger.flink.name = org.apache.flink
      logger.flink.level = ERROR

      # The following lines keep the log level of common libraries/connectors on
      # log level INFO. The root logger does not override this. You have to manually
      # change the log levels here.
      logger.akka.name = akka
      logger.akka.level = ERROR
      logger.kafka.name= org.apache.kafka
      logger.kafka.level = ERROR
      logger.hadoop.name = org.apache.hadoop
      logger.hadoop.level = ERROR
      logger.zookeeper.name = org.apache.zookeeper
      logger.zookeeper.level = ERROR

      # Log all infos to the console
      appender.console.name = ConsoleAppender
      appender.console.type = CONSOLE
      appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
      appender.console.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p %-60c %x - %m%n

      # Log all infos in the given rolling file
      appender.rolling.name = RollingFileAppender
      appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
      appender.rolling.append = false
      appender.rolling.fileName = ${sys:log.file}
      appender.rolling.filePattern = ${sys:log.file}.%i
      appender.rolling.layout.type = PatternLayout
      appender.rolling.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p %-60c %x - %m%n
      appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies
      appender.rolling.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
      appender.rolling.policies.size.size=100MB
      appender.rolling.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
      appender.rolling.strategy.max = 10

      # Suppress the irrelevant (wrong) warnings from the Netty channel handler
      logger.netty.name = org.apache.flink.shaded.akka.org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline
      logger.netty.level = OFF
```

I don't see the logs of my application anywhere in the TaskManager. Anyone knows what I'm missing in the configuration?

Comment: logger.flink.level is set to ERROR. No errors, then log will be empty. Can you change it to INFO, i.e. `logger.flink.level = INFO` ?

Comment: @AlexeyNovakov I want Flink package (`org.apache.flink.*`) logs to be ERROR but my application logs to be INFO. 

Running the job on Flink 1.14.3 with Spotify operator.

Comment: Can you share your program code to see how an instance of a logger constructed and where it is used to log messages?

Comment: I use lombok to init the logger with annotation `@slf4j`

Comment: I think unless you show us the code example how the logger is instantiated and where log4j properties file is located, it will be hard to answer your question. Above properties file looks fine, I guess the problem somewhere in the middle.